# powershell sort-object doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, quest

I tried to use sort-object cmdlet to sort processes by Id's here:

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property Id
```

and it works well. In any other example I found, sorting works fine, but when I try to sort employees by their employeeID from Active Directory with this one-liner:

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties -SerializeValues | ? {?_.Mail} | select employeeID | sort-object -property employeeID
```

I get something like this:

```
11
1104
1105
1185
119
12
...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Get-QADUser returns eployeeId as a string, thus sort uses string sorting mechanism.
To sort employeeIds as integers - just cast property to this type:

```
Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties | Sort-Object { [int]$_.employeeId } | select Name, employeeid
```

Answer (score 2):

Also u can use {$_.employeeId -as [int]}. This dont cause error in null.

I take this solution with "Frode F."